# Can't change directory in Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, console

I'm trying to change directories and I'm not sure why this isn't working.  Currently it's stuck on L:\Code\Scripts pathway.  When I type:

```
cd d/ C:
```

The console reads "The system cannot find the path specified."

I also cannot set the directory to L:\Code (i.e one level back in the path) as it seems to be stuck in L:\Code\Scripts.

I am using Windows (10 I believe). What can I try next?

Comment: Maybe a proper switch character placement could help: `cd /d c:`?

Comment: what are you want actually, change the drive or one level back from current path??

Comment: Feasibly I'd like to do both, depending on the situation. Character change did not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need to use, *note the back slash which designates a directory instead of a drive*!

```
CD/D C:\
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are currently at `L:\Code\Scripts>` and then want to

**Change the drive(i.e, from drive L to C) then type `c:`**

```
L:\Code\Scripts>c:
C:\>
```

**one level back from current path then type `cd..`**

```
L:\Code\Scripts>cd..
L:\Code>
```

Comment: Using cd still reverts me back to L:\Code\Scripts.  Not sure why.

Comment: Also, using L: reverts me back to L:\Code\Scripts.  Could it be something in my environment variables?

Comment: if you type `cd` only then it reverts back. You have to use `cd..` as I mention in the answer.

Comment: if you are already in drive L on some path and you type `L:` then it reverts back.

Comment: Isn't there a way to save L://Code/Scripts as an environmental variable to access it more easily?

Comment: You can first go to that folder and press `shift key + right key` then new option comes `open command window here`.